# UIScrollView paging layout on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uicontainerview

I am making an universal demo xcode project which is a `UIScrollView` contains two pages, scroll left and right to go back and forth.

My questions is iPad and iPhone's layout is not the same.

1. I created 3 view controllers in storyboard as below:

[image]

`ViewController` has the `UIScrollView`.

`AViewController` contains an `UILabel` in the center("`Good morning...`").

`BViewController` contains an `UILabel` in the center("`Good night...`").

2. The constraints of the UILabels are:

[image]

3. Here is the code of `ViewController`:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let vc1 = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewController")
           let vc2 = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BViewController")
           vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
           vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           addContentView([vc1, vc2])
           scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2, height: scrollView.frame.height)
       }

       func addContentView(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
           viewControllers.enumerated().forEach {
               addChildViewController($1)
               $1.view.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat($0), y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
               scrollView.addSubview($1.view)
               didMove(toParentViewController: $1)
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. If I choose **View as iPhone 8** then the layout works correct in iPhone 8 like this: (Swipe then from green to red)

[image]

But for iPad:

[image]

**The labels are not centered!!**.

If I choose **View as iPad ...** ,then for iPhone it doesn't layout correct.

Here is the view hierarchy, it's obvious the layout is correct but for some reason the green view is larger than screen size and covered by the red one.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

The code is here: https://github.com/williamhqs/TestLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded view controller views have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` by default which introduces bogus constraints:
[image: AutoresizingMask Constraints]
Setting it to false will not let you just set the frame manually, so you will have to write the full layout. It's slightly more verbose, but autolayout will work for the embedded view controllers and you get rotation support as well:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc1 = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewController")
    let vc2 = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BViewController")
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    addContentView([vc1, vc2])
}

func addContentView(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    var previousController: UIViewController? = nil
    viewControllers.forEach {
        addChildViewController($0)
        $0.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview($0.view)

        $0.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        $0.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        if let trailing = previousController?.view.trailingAnchor {
            $0.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing).isActive = true
        } else {
            $0.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        $0.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        $0.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        previousController = $0
    }
    previousController?.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Scroll view works as expected for all devices, regardless of the Xcode View as setting:
[image]
[image]